# How to avoid no-async/await in loop?

Tags: node.js, async-await

We can easy refactor no await in loop if there is a single async/await. But sometime, in loop we have some awaits and the next await uses the result of previous await. So how to avoid that error with case multiple await in loop ?

I want to avoid this issue because I just added eslint rule to the project and no-await-in-loop is an error eslint reported. It's suggesting refactor to use Promise.all to run multiple async process in parallel. It can make increasing speed for performance.

ex:

```
for (const item in items) {
  // first await
  const firstResult = await getOneItem(...);

  // second await
  const secondResult = await getOneItem({ // conditions based on first result });

  ...
}
```

Comment: There's absolutely nothing wrong with `await`ing inside a loop if that's what the logic you need to implement requires. Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: even without async in an example, `console.log(new Array(5))` would have `5` being evaluated and put as the parameter for `Array` and then that is evaluated and put as the parameter for `console.log` and then the logging would happen.. it's just how the language works ;-;

Comment: @CertainPerformance Zer0: I just added eslint and there is an error of eslint reports, no-await-in-loop. I just want to push the sync process to Promise.all and they can run in parallel process.

Comment: If second result is `conditions based on first result `, you cannot make it in parallel because you need to wait for the first result and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pass a `.then` when inside the mapper function to `Promise.all` to wait for the first Promise to resolve and execute the second promise depending on its result. Something like:

```
return Promise.all(
  items.map(
    item => getOneItem(item)
      .then((itemResult) => {
        // insert desired logic here
        return getOneItem(itemResult.someProperty);
      })
  )
);
```

If you have more than two, either keep returning `.then`s:

```
return Promise.all(
  items.map(
    item => getOneItem(item)
      .then((itemResult) => {
        // insert desired logic here
        return getOneItem(itemResult.someProperty);
      })
      .then((secondItemResult) => {
        // insert desired logic here
      })
  )
);
```

Or use an async function in the mapper callback so you can `await`:

```
return Promise.all(
  items.map(
    async (item) => {
      const result1 = await getOneItem(item);
      const result2 = await getOneItem(result1.someProperty);
      // etc
    )
);
```

Comment: 2 await is just example, if. have more than we can facing with "promise hell" ?

Comment: I just read your updated comment, in the last block if you put await in map, you went back to root error again.

Comment: That shouldn't give the `no-await-in-loop` error - you're no longer in a loop, but in a callback. If it gives an error, which rule is violated?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` with an `async` callback:

```
await Promise.all(items.map(async item => {
  let result1 = await getOneItem(item);
  return getOneItem(result1);
}));
```

Comment: It's still facing with no-await-in-loop because we put the await inside map callback function

Comment: Well, you've created this problem for yourself. There's nothing at all wrong with this approach. If a linting program is giving you an issue, I recommend you disable that program.